# topology notation $G \backslash X$

Tags: general-topology, group-theory

Suppose there is a group $G$ acting on space $X$.

What does the following notation mean? $$G \backslash X$$
Thank you!

Comment: Typically, I believe this refers to the orbit space of $X$ under the action of $G$, i.e. the equivalence classes of elements of $X$ where $x \sim y$ if there is some $g \in G$ such that $gx = y$.

Comment: @AlexWertheim that makes sense. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, sometimes it is written as $X/G$, but $G\backslash X$ is written in cases where you want to make clear that $G$ acts from a different side from the "usual."

Comment: @ThomasAndrews thank you!